How to pass Users $deltaToken in Microsoft.Graph v5.53.0
I had a problem that when I updated the Microsoft.Graph library from v3 to v5.53.0, everything broke. I have already found a rough solution, but the problem is that I have a deltaToken that I want to pass to the API, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Here is what I have
public class SyncGraphServiceClient(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ILogger<SyncGraphServiceClient> logger) : IGraphServiceClient
{
    private const string DeltaTokenQueryKey = "%24$deltatoken";

    private static string[] UserProperties = ["displayName", "mail"];

    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    private readonly ILogger<ADSyncGraphServiceClient> _logger = logger;

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public async Task<UserCollectionResponse> PerformUsersDeltaQueryAsync(Uri deltaUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var queries = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(deltaUrl.Query);
        var deltaRequest = _graphServiceClient.Users.Delta.ToGetRequestInformation(
            (requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 10;
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = UserProperties;
            });
        deltaRequest.QueryParameters.Add(DeltaTokenQueryKey, queries.Get("$deltatoken"));

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(deltaRequest, UserCollectionResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
}

I will be very grateful if you can help in any way!
Thank you!
Updated the Microsoft.Graph library.
You need to use the new approach of this library.

After the release of v5 I had to upgrade from v4 and it was horrible. Everything is changed. Especially that you can't use STJ or Newtonsoft directly anymore on SDK entities and that the objects are stateful with regard to serialization. When you get around these big issues, the new version can be used much better then the old one and the usage of user delta tokens in v5 is documented here and the call of the next values here

var result = await graphClient.Users.Delta.WithUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltatoken=oEcOySpF_hWYmTIUZBOIfPzcwisr_rPe8o9M54L45qEXQGmvQC6T2dbL-9O7nSU-njKhFiGlAZqewNAThmCVnNxqPu5gOBegrm1CaVZ-ZtFZ2tPOAO98OD9y0ao460").GetAsDeltaGetResponseAsync(); from the Get incremental changes for users API

graph sdk v4 to v5 : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md    and graph sdk v3 to v4: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md
